# How do I diplay Json markers on react native maps?

Tags: reactjs, native, react-native-maps

I am stuck on how I can map a JSON to react native maps. I tried a few ways to map each coordinate The JSON file from API:

```
{
    "request_time": "2019-09-28T22:13:25+01:00",
    "source": "NaPTAN",
    "acknowledgements": "Contains DfT NaPTAN bus stops data",
    "member": [
        {
            "type": "bus_stop",
            "name": "Western Avenue - SW-bound",
            "description": "Buckingham",
            "latitude": 52.00437,
            "longitude": -0.98989,
            "accuracy": 20,
            "atcocode": "040000004581",
            "distance": 846.0
        },
        {
            "type": "bus_stop",
            "name": "Overn Avenue - NE-bound",
            "description": "Buckingham",
            "latitude": 52.00378,
            "longitude": -0.98884,
            "accuracy": 20,
            "atcocode": "040000002388",
            "distance": 872.0
        }
    ]
}
```

In this MapView section you will see the map method I am using, the markers are not being displayed for some reason. I am getting a TypeError: this.state.markers.map is not a function:

```
          <MapView
              style={styles.map}
              showsUserLocation={true}
              initialRegion={{
                  latitude: this.state.latitude,
                  longitude: this.state.longitude,
                  latitudeDelta: 0.0462,
                  longitudeDelta: 0.0261,
          }}
          >

              {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                  <Marker
                      coordinate={{ latitude: marker.member.latitude, longitude: marker.member.longitude}}
                  />
              ))}

          </MapView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from your actual code, make the following change

```
 getBusStops = () => {
    try {
        axios.get(`http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/places.json?lat=${this.state.latitude}&lon=${this.state.longitude}&type=bus_stop&app_id=xxxx&app_key=xxxxxxxx`)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ markers: response.data.member});
                console.log(this.state.markers);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state.markers.map is not a function` means that you are trying to use `map` function on a non array variable which is `this.state.markers` in this case.

I think that `this.state.markers` is `undefined` when `react native component` first renders otherwise double check if `this.state.markers` is an `array` not an `object`.

You could also do a check before rendering in case of `undefined`.

```
this.state.markers && this.state.markers.map(marker => ( 
                 <Marker
                      coordinate={{ latitude: marker.member.latitude, longitude: marker.member.longitude}}
                  />
              ))}
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. Here is my expo: https://snack.expo.io/S1rcu7guB

Answer (score 0):

Ive experienced the same road block try assigning this.state to const then use the return() statement to stop the execution of a function and return the value of the expression.

// see the example below.

```html
          
 render() {

    const { markers } = this.state;


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          
          <MapView
              style={styles.map}
              showsUserLocation={true}
              initialRegion={{
                  latitude: this.state.latitude,
                  longitude: this.state.longitude,
                  latitudeDelta: 0.0462,
                  longitudeDelta: 0.0261,
          }}
          >

              {markers.map((marker, index ) => {
                return  (
                  <Marker
                      coordinate={{ latitude: marker.member.latitude, longitude: marker.member.longitude}}
                  />
                  
                  )
              ))}

          </MapView>
    );
  }
}
```

additionally for your reference, here is a source code of a working example attached with a screenshot of how the markers are spread out. In this case it's a custom marker which renders item.price from the JSON.

The format of the json coordinates are as such:
"geopoints: "55.263237,25.009765","

therefore I have written a separate function to make it compatible.

However you can leverage the format most compatible with your data structure.

[image]

```html
componentDidMount() {
        return fetch("www.yourUrlGoesHere.com/Json", { cache: "reload" })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                const mapArray = responseJson.properties.filter((item) => {
                  if (typeof(item.photo) !== 'undefined' && item.photo.length)
                      return item.property_type && item.property_type.toUpperCase();
                });
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: mapArray
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }


  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const { dataSource } = this.state;


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <MapView initialRegion={{
          latitude: 25.2048,
          longitude: 55.2708,
          latitudeDelta: 0.122,
          longitudeDelta: 0.121
        }} style={styles.map}>
        {dataSource.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Marker
              key={`marker-${item.listing_ref}`}
              coordinate = {{
              latitude : item.geopoints.split(",")[1] - 0,
              longitude : item.geopoints.split(",")[0] - 0,
              }}
            >
        
                <View
                  style={[
                    styles.marker,
                    styles.shadow,

                  ]}
                >
                  <Text style={{marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10,fontSize : 8, fontWeight:"bold", color : "black"}}>د.إ {numeral(item.price).format('0.0a')}</Text>

                </View>
       
            </Marker>
        );
      })}


        </MapView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```